# Not getting data from Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I am using Core Data to store some information for my app.
I have a .xcdatamodeld file containing 8 entities, and I extract them on different views.

In one of the viewControllers, I call three of them. Like this:

```
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];


NSEntityDescription *entiAll = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AllWeapons" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
NSFetchRequest *frAll = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[frAll setEntity:entiAll];
NSError *error = nil;
arrAll = [moc executeFetchRequest:frAll error:&error];
displayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:arrAll];


NSEntityDescription *entiRange = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"WeaponsRanged" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
NSFetchRequest *frRanged = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[frRanged setEntity:entiRange];
NSError *errorRanged = nil;
arrRange = [moc executeFetchRequest:frRanged error:&errorRanged];
NSLog(@"%i, %i", [arrRange count], [[moc executeFetchRequest:frRanged error:&errorRanged] count]);


NSEntityDescription *entiMelee = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"WeaponsMelee" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
NSFetchRequest *frMelee = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[frMelee setEntity:entiMelee];
NSError *errorMelee = nil;
arrMelee = [moc executeFetchRequest:frMelee error:&errorMelee];
NSLog(@"%i, %i", [arrMelee count], [[moc executeFetchRequest:frMelee error:&errorMelee] count]);
```

The problem is that the middle one (the one filling the arrRange-array) doesn't work..

arrAll logs out with all correct data, arrMelee logs out with all the correct data (x4 for some reason, don't know if this is related :S), but arrRange logs out as an empty array. 
`[arrRange count];` gives me 0, even though I know there is lots of data there. 
I ran this code on the simulator, and found the .sqlite file, opened it in Firefox's SQLite Manager, and saw the correct data, 40 rows.

I went into the appDelegate, where I fill the CoreData when necessary, and saw that the method  which downloads the data in JSON-format successfully sends it to the sqlite aswell.

Here I fill the CoreData with data from the json:

```
[self deleteAllObjects:@"WeaponsRanged"];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

for(NSDictionary *item in jsonWeaponRanged)
{
    WeaponsRanged *wr = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"WeaponsRanged" 
                    inManagedObjectContext:context];
    ///***///
    wr.recoil = [item objectForKey:@"Recoil"];
    ///***///

     NSError *error;
    if(![context save:&error])
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

And if I here do `NSLog(@"%@ - %@", wr.recoil, [item objectForKey:@"Recoil"]);` I get the correct data. (Same data on both)

So. The correct data is obviously in the core. But my NSFetchRequest or something is failing. I am pretty noob at Objective-C, so it might be my bad code-grammar striking again. I realize I should use things again etc, not creating new objects all the time.. But cmon, this is my first app.. And if that is actually the problem, I might learn. But I'm stuck.

SOMETIMES I get data, sometimes I don't. It's weird. I re-launched the app, and got data from it, and now I don't.. I haven't found a pattern yet..

Anyone? 
Or is there another way to request data from the entity?

Comment: Are you getting your JSON data from the web? If so, can you show the code for your loading routine.

Comment: Hm.. I do not think this has anything to do with it.. As I said, the data is always in coredata, but doesn't get returned on query. I have used the same method in all of them, and I have proved that the .sqlite contains the data by opening it in the SQLite Manager in FireFox.

Comment: Could you iterate over the array and print `WeaponsRanged` object? For example `for(NSManagedObject* obj in arrRange) { NSLog(@"--> %@", [obj valueForKey:@"aKey"]); }`. Let me know what you see.

Comment: @Flex_Addicted Hm.. When I started the app in the simulator now, I couldn't reproduce the error. I have no idea when it strikes. I have done nothing since I wrote the post. So that logged out lots of stuff. However, when I ran it on the ios device, it didn't show anything. The array is empty when it doesn't work. [arrRange count] = 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind! It was my own damn fault (yet again..).

The problem occured before the code I presented, and it turns out the data was never in the .sqlite-file when the problem was present.

This is what I had:

I collected data from the internet through json-request. I have told the app to check the "version" of the data through the internet, and if the data is outdated, then re-download it.

First, I download all data, then I add them to their own entity in Core Data. After downloading, I clear the current Core Data entity of the downloaded data. So on the top of each add-method it said i.e `[self deleteAllObjectsOfEntity:@"WeaponsRanged"];`, My whole problem was that in the `addMelee`-method, it ALSO said `[self deleteAllObjectsOfEntity:@"WeaponsRanged"];` instead of `@"WeaponsMelee"`, thus deleting all ranged weapons, and later adding melee to the melee entity. And that also proves that the other problem I mentioned of arrMelee logging out four times as much data as it should was caused by this.

The reason it sometimes worked was that the downloading is not happening in any ordered mode. So the `addRanged` was sometimes called before the `addMelee`. If ranged comes first, it clears the arrRanged, and fills it up with correct data, and THEN melee comes, and clears it out. When melee was called first, it cleared arrRanged and filled additional data to arrMelee, and THEN ranged comes and tries to clear an empty entity, and then fills it up with correct data.

The solution was obviously to change the entity deleted when adding it, as it was the wrong one.

Sorry.... :)

Answer (score 2):

I have some suggestions, too big for a comment.

1) after you create the WeaponsRanged, try reading them back:

```
for(NSDictionary *item in jsonWeaponRanged)
{
    WeaponsRanged *wr = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"WeaponsRanged" 
                    inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSLog(@"IS WR Realized? %@", wr ? @"YES" : @"NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO WR");
    ///***///
    wr.recoil = [item objectForKey:@"Recoil"];
    ///***///

     NSError *error;
    if(![context save:&error])
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

// Now lets see if we can retrieve them:
{
    NSEntityDescription *entiRange = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"WeaponsRanged" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *frRanged = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [frRanged setEntity:entiRange];
    NSError *errorRanged = nil;
    arrRange = [context executeFetchRequest:frRanged error:&errorRanged];
    NSLog(@"Wrote %i items, read back %i items", [jsonWeaponRanged count], [arrRange count] );
}
```

2) In the viewController reading WeaponsRanged, add an assert before the fetch on mod:

```
    NSLog(@"IS moc set? %@", moc ? @"YES" : @"NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO MOC");
```

EDIT:

3) Spread statements everywhere you access the MOC:

```
assert([NSThread isMainThread]);
```

[If you haven't used asserts before google and read up on the topic. These are a powerful tool for developers to find out about potential problems way before they manifest themselves in the gui or elsewhere. They are normally compiled out for release/distribution builds.]

This will force an exception if the thread is not the main thread, and then let you track down the reason by following the stack trace.

Comment: I can assure you that the data gets saved properly, as I can preview the .sqlite file and see the data. BUT, now I can't reproduce the problem on the simulator. When I launch the simulator, it shows everything. When I launch it on the device, it has the same problem as before. It is completely random, earlier it was the other way around. I have no idea what's causing this.. The assert did not work.. (I don't really know what it does, but it didn't fix this..)

Comment: Asserts just say - I "assert" what is inside is true. So it didn't work - it crashed? That means moc is nil. Change the asserts to NSLogs and make sure the values inside the asserts are not nil. Also, if you don't want to try the code I gave you, since you know the sql is proper, well then, I guess you can fix it yourself. Its not just me - others are reading this. You're telling us the SQL looks great does nothing to solve the basic issue - which is Core Data apparently is now working for you. For the record its working for millions of people all over the world right now.

Comment: No, it didn't crash. Nothing crashes, I just don't get any information from the request. moc is set. And as you see, I always use the same moc to all three requests. Maybe that is the problem? But that doesn't explain how it works sometimes.. For me, it seems like the fetch is bugged. As if the return of a "SELECT * FROM Table" is empty. It still returns as an array, but an empty array. I can't tell why it is empty sometimes.. Right now I am unable to reproduce the problem.. And I have done nothing to fix it. Seems random. I don't want it to happen after launch..

Comment: Core Data is being used by thousands if not hundreds of thousands of developers, and millions of users. It has been exhaustively tested and vetted. I've used it for years and years on Mac an iOS, and NEVER had a problem that I could not track down to my coding problem. Obviously, YMMV. If you EVER inadvertantly access it from a second thread then for sure all bets are off.

Comment: Well, this is ios6 beta, så I'm not so sure anymore.. I don't know where to put my nslogs to check what's going on anymore.. It all worked well, then suddenly, sometimes it doesn't show. The sqlite contains the data, so what could cause the fetch to sometimes not return anything..?

Comment: I would suggest posting on the private apple lists relative to iOS6 beta and see if anyone else is experiencing problems with the beta. Likewise, I'd enter a bugreport on it, as bugs against betas get more attention. Apple will either ignore it, dup it, or ask for a sample project that duplicates the problem. Ask me how I know this :-) Good luck!

Comment: I found the problem. It was, as usual, my own fault. See posted solution for more info.. Thank you for all your help, and for learning me to use assert()!